# Modifiable Global Variable c++

Tags: c++, global-variables

I need to include a header file in multiple CPP files that contains a range of global variables. But the problem I am having is that I cant seem to make the variables modifiable. I can initialize the variable in the header file, or in any of the cpp files, but when I come to change it, it either won't compile or its creating 2 instances of the variable that are out of scope of one and another. I need a way that will allow me to change the value in function.

Example using static (It creates instances of the variables outside the scope of the other variables)

```
#pragma once

namespace SCE
{
static bool SC_DEBUG = false;
static bool VSYNC = true;
static int SC_LOG_LEVEL = 3;
}
```

Ive also tried using 'extern' but I have had no luck with that either.

```
    #pragma once

namespace SCE
{
    extern bool SC_DEBUG;
    extern bool VSYNC;
    extern int SC_LOG_LEVEL;
}
```

**Edit**
I get the error "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "bool SCE::VSYNC" (?VSYNC@SCE@@3_NA)", when I try and edit the variable once it's created using extern. The way I try and edit it is like so

```
int main()
{
    SCE::VSYNC = false;
    // ...
}
```

**Solution**
I'm using a multi-project setup. So what is happening is that 'Project B' contains the Global Variable header file and the cpp, whilst 'Project A' is attempting to change the value once it's been set. Now for some reason, since 'Project A' is only pulling the Global variable header file, its getting the variable definitions but can't see the initialization of the variables, thus throwing a slew of strange errors.

Answer (score 0):

In a header file define the variables with `extern`:

```
// globals.h
namespace SCE
{
    extern bool SC_DEBUG;
    extern bool VSYNC;
    extern int SC_LOG_LEVEL;
}
```

And define them in an implementation file:

```
// globals.cpp
namespace SCE
{
    bool SC_DEBUG = false;
    bool VSYNC = true;
    int SC_LOG_LEVEL = 3;
}
```

Now you can include the header into your other files.

Comment: That's not the problem I'm having, I can create them fine, but when it comes to editing them, I get the error error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "bool SCE::VSYNC" (?VSYNC@SCE@@3_NA)

Comment: @0xen Have you included all your files into your project? If `globals.cpp` isn't included, you will get that error.

Comment: Yes, it compiles and runs fine when I don't try and edit the variable like shown above in my edit.

Comment: @0xen How are you compiling and linking? Because Bob's code should be fine, you should be able to modify those variables.

Comment: I think you may be missing some `#include`'s.

Comment: @GregKikola I have the Global.h and Global.cpp set up the same. I'm including the Global.h in both Cpp files that will be using it, and editing the variable with SCO::VSYNC = false;

Comment: In `global.h`, there should be `#include global.cpp`, and then in your other files, `#include global.h`. Then it should work. The error you are getting is due to missing the implementation file.

Comment: I have found the problem, ill make a right up about it, but its because I'm using a multi-project setup and each project seems to have its own global varable instance

Comment: Ahh, right, that sounds confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little unclear. It seems you are facing problem with static variables. Static variables are capable of preserving their value even if they are out of scope. They remain in the memory till program runs. For eg.

```
#include<stdio.h>
static int i = 0;
int fun()
{
     i= i+5;
}

int main()
{
     fun();
     printf("%d ", i);
     i= 10,
     printf("%d ", i);
     return 0;
}
```

Output: 5 10